# Unable to find matching line from backtrace RSPEC with rails 3.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've updated to 3.0.10 because of the sql injection vulnerability.  After I updated, I ran the tests and all of them started throwing the above error along with the following lines.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
SystemStackError:
  stack level too deep
# /home/part/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:153
```

Comment: What version of rspec are you using? And are you working with database transaction rollbacks?

Comment: rspec and rspec rails is both 2.6.0.  I've just figured out that the problem is with factory_girl.  I get the stack level too deep error when I create a factory

Comment: Can you try setting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` it should be in your spec_helper.rb. Line 153 of database_statements.rb deals with transactions and that might be the issue.

Comment: But I need to run the tests inside a transaction.  Not doing so would mean a lot of test code changes.

Comment: I've tried setting the transactional fixtures to true but I still get the same error.

Comment: Alright, well there goes my best guess. Do you have any sort of a longer stacktrace?

Comment: I'm getting this too.

Turning turning off/on transactional fixtures, and it made no difference. This is causing major problems for me now because a great slab of specs are now meaningless.

Comment: has anyone solved this?  Just updated rspec to 2.8 and it created this behavior for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced a similar error while running Cucumber features when upgrading my project from Rails `2.3.8` to `3.2.2`. There's almost no way that I know you can find out the stack trace of this error.

The real problem, in my case, was double inclusion of a library, called rest-client, once as a plugin, and once as a gem. It was in my Gemfile, as well as in my vendor/plugins directory. Maybe you can make a quick check if there's anything like that with your project.

I found this out by a tedious process of using 'raise' at several places of my code. In your execution path of the rspec statement that causes this error, put raise method calls at different places, e.g.

```
raise StandardError, 'code did reach here'
```

That, with some binary search logic, will get you close to the culprit code. Once you're there, use the following construct to get a stack trace.

```
begin
  # culprit code is here
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  puts e.backtrace.inspect
end
```

That worked for me at least, hope it helps you.